# vertical space between equations and between equations and the text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

Since I use double spacing and the `\begin{align*}` seems to create too much space between the equations and the text and between the equations, I often use just `\begin{center} $...$ \end{center}`. But when I need to align, I can't use it. So my question is how can I make `\begin{align*}` just look like `\begin{center} $ ...$ \end{center}`. I tried `-2\jot` or `-1.5\jot`, but it looks a little different...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! We would appreciate you to provide some more information (e.g. the way you achieved the double-spacing or better a whole MWE).

Comment: Does [Where does the space before \align* come from?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337104/64454) help?

Answer (score 1):

For align you can define verrtical spaces with `pt`:

```
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{20pt} % used for space above equotation
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{20pt} % used for space below equotation
```

Space between equotations or between equotations and text is the same for align.

It is also possible to use something like that with upsetting and stretchable parts:

```
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{10pt plus 2pt minus 5pt}%default
```

Comment: That is not entirely true. Equation can change the spacing above it self depending on the size of the material inside the equation env and the length of the line of text preceeding it. The align env cannot.

Comment: @daleif. Exact.