# Spacing of align environment inside subfigure

Tags: align, subcaption, vertical-spacing

I like to enclose two subfigures, which I use to display align environments side by side in a framebox. However, this leads to ugly padding at the top of the box.

[image]

A earlier post ([Where does the space before \align* come from?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337104/where-does-the-space-before-align-come-from)) emphasizes, that it is never a good idea to have a par before a math environment.

I am curious whether this is the problem here and how to avoid it.

Please note, that I need the align environment indeed and that the problem seems not to depend of its content.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,headsepline,footsepline,DIV=13,BCOR=12mm,bibliography=toc,chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% serveral packages

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{lipsum} %%% can be delted in the end !!!!!!

% figures and captions

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain, width=.9\textwidth}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[h]%
    \framebox[\textwidth]{\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{align*}%
                E = m \cdot c^2
            \end{align*}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}%
            \begin{align*}%
                E = m \cdot c^2
            \end{align*}
    \end{subfigure}}
    \caption{Some caption.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Might you make a better example that shows the need for `subfigure`?

Answer (score 1):

By use of the `empheq` package and `flalign` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength\fboxsep{6pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{empheq}[box=\fcolorbox{red}{white}]{flalign*}
&&  
    F & = ma    
& 
  E &= mc^2   
&&
    \end{empheq}
\lipsum[2]
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Basic Solution

`\usepackage{adjustbox}`

Manual: https://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox

See, (Sec 4.2) `margin=<left> <bottom> <right> <top>`

In use:

```
\begin{figure} % ...
% ...
\begin{adjustbox}{margin=0em 0em 0em -1em, varwidth=\textwidth,fbox,center}
% ...
% subfigures, etc.. go here
% ...
\end{adjustbox}
% ...
\end{figure}
```

Effect: Shift the box *up* `1em`.

### Details

Overlooking the rationale for embedding subfigures, it looks like there are a few methods to solve this.  I used `adjustbox` to solve it.

Requires a package `adjustbox`

https://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox

I just set the top margin to `-1em`

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]%
  \begin{adjustbox}{margin=0em 0em 0em -1em, 
                    varwidth=\textwidth,fbox,center}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{align*}%
                E &= mc^2
            \end{align*}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{align*}%
                E &= mc^2
            \end{align*}
        \end{subfigure}
   \end{adjustbox}
\caption{Energy is matter is energy.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the spacing above and below the `align` environments to zero (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47403/47927)). If you do this inside the `figure` environment, these settings are only applied within this environment.

It may be true that it is not a good idea to place a math environment directly after a `\par`, but since you wrap the `align` environment inside a `figure`, I think that this should not be a problem here.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, headsepline, footsepline, DIV=13, BCOR=12mm, bibliography=toc, chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% serveral packages

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{lipsum} %%% can be delted in the end !!!!!!

% figures and captions

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain, width=.9\textwidth}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[h]%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \framebox[\textwidth]{%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}%
            \begin{align*}%
                E = m \cdot c^2
            \end{align*}%
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}%
            \begin{align*}%
                E = m \cdot c^2
            \end{align*}%
        \end{subfigure}%
    }
    \caption{Some caption.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
%
\begin{align*}%
    E = m \cdot c
\end{align*}
%
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for `subfigure`, unless you want to have subcaptions. Nor I see reasons for `align*` when a single equation is involved.

Anyway, use `$\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}$` for multiline displays or `$\displaystyle...$` for a single equation.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,headsepline,footsepline,DIV=13,BCOR=12mm,bibliography=toc,chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% serveral packages

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{lipsum} %%% can be delted in the end !!!!!!

% figures and captions

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain, width=.9\textwidth}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[htp]

\framebox[\textwidth]{%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    $\begin{aligned}
      E &= m \cdot c^2 \\
      F &= ma
    \end{aligned}$
  \caption{Subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    $\begin{aligned}
      E &= m \cdot c^2 \\
      F &= ma
    \end{aligned}$
  \caption{Subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}%
}% end of \framebox

\caption{Some caption.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]